# Python program for determining which value appears in my dictionary the most times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have come up with this program but it is not working. I need to determine which value in my list appears the most. For example which prey is eaten the most by the predators.
Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
max_value=0
for pred in dictionary:
     for prey in dictionary[pred]:
         if len(dictionary[pred]) >= max_value:
       max_value= len(dictionary[pred])
       p=prey
       print(p)
```

Comment: Either your indentation is off, or you don't have any code under `if len(dictionary[pred]) >= max_value:`. The semicolon implies that it will have a series of commands to execute if the test is true. However, there are no commands in the said test.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter):

```
dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':42, 'c':3, 'd':42}

from collections import Counter

cntr = Counter(value for value in dictionary.values())
print cntr.most_common(1)
```

Output:

```
[(42, 2)]
```

Which shows the the most common value and how many times it occurred. Note there could be a ties, you may have to do further processing of the results returned by `most_common()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at `heapq` to get the n longest:

```
>>> d = {1: [1, 2], 2:[2,3,4])
>>> heapq.nlargest(1, d.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): len(v))
(2, [2, 3, 4])
```

or use `max`:

```
>>> max(d.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): len(v))
(2, [2, 3, 4])
```

Will get you an arbitrary result for values that have equal lengths though.